# Passing function into ng-repeat object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

so I have a problem with ng-repeat directive. In my code I have a parent controller which have data stored as array of objects.

```
$scope.queue = [
  {
    name: 'Mark',
    sex: 'Male',
    age: 21
  },
  {...}
];

$scope.changePositionInQueue = function (currIndex, targetIndex) {
  // move up / down person in queue 
};
```

What I want to do is pass parent controller's function to my directive's ('person') isolated scope and at the same time be able to use '$index', '$first', '$last' variables.

```
<person data-change-position="changePositionInQueue" data-person="person" ng-repeat="person in queue"></person>
```

Directive scope declaration:

```
scope: {
 person: '=',
 changePosition: '&'
}
```

The problem is that when I create isolated scope inside ng-repeat loop I lose ng-repeat properties. On the other hand when I create default scope by ng-repeat and I have access to all wanted properties I can't use parent function.

Comment: so even pass those on scope as parameters to your isolate scope directive

Comment: Thanks for answer, but how can I do it? Passing parameters as person.$index or $index gives me 'undefined' in directive child scope.

Comment: something like `index: @` in your directive definition of scope and then on html `data-index="$index"` should do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution to your challenge:
In view:

```
<my-directive dir-func="fnc($index)" data="data" ng-repeat="data in datas"><span>{{data.id|json}}</span><br></my-directive>
```

In Direct call parent function in link:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    //require: 'ngModle',
    scope: {
      data: "=",
      dirFunc: "&"
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
        scope.dirFunc() // parent scope.func is called here where you get the alert

    }

  }
```

[See the Plunker for detail](https://plnkr.co/edit/GipaoWvWt0RqHHAqwpKZ?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It wasn't helped me directly becouse I figured it out by getting $index property from $parent scope, but my function still wasn't worked properly. I found a mistake by looking at your directive. I was passing function by reference in my directive without giving informations about arguments it takes. Problem solved anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad that help, the purpose of example is for that! :) Cheer!